# How can I copy each element of a list a distinct, specified number of times?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am using python 3 and I want to create a new list with elements from a the first list repeated as many times as the respective number of the second list

For example:

```
char = ['a', 'b', 'c']
int = [2, 4, 3]
result = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c']
```

Thx all for help

Comment: @MarcoBallabio can you please post a code sample telling us what you tried so we can help you go further?

Comment: Use for loops... and don't use int as a variable name since it's also a function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**One-liner solution**

Iterate over both lists simultaneously with `zip`, and create sub-lists for each element with the correct length. Join them with `itertools.chain`:

```
# from itertools import chain
list(chain(*([l]*n for l, n in zip(char, int))))
```

Output:

```
['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
char = ['a', 'b', 'c']
ints = [2, 4, 3]
```

Solution 1: Using numpy

```
import numpy as np
result = np.repeat(char, ints)
```

Solution 2: Pure python

```
result = []
for i, c in zip(ints, char):
    result.extend(c*i)
```

Output:

```
['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c']
```

Comment: Surprisingly the timeit stats are really bad for this compared to list-comprehension and itertools method.

Answer (score 0):

Using `zip`

**Ex:**

```
c = ['a', 'b', 'c']
intVal = [2, 4, 3]

result = []
for i, v in zip(c, intVal):
    result.extend(list(i*v))
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c']
```

Answer (score 0):

With for loops, very basic:

```
results = list()
for k, i in enumerate(integers):
    results_to_add = char[k]*i
    results.extend(results_to_add)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
char = ['a', 'b', 'c']
rep = [2, 4, 3]

res = [c*i.split(",") for i,c in zip(char, rep )]      # [['a', 'a'], ['b', 'b', 'b', 'b'], ['c', 'c', 'c']]
print([item for sublist in res for item in sublist])   # flattening the list
```

**EDIT**:

one-liner using `itertools.chain`:

```
print(list(chain(*[c*i.split(",") for (i,c) in zip(char, int)])))
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c']
```

Answer (score 0):

One liner using list-comprehension and `sum(list_, [])`.

```
sum([[x]*y for x,y in zip(char_, int_)], [])


>>> char_ = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> int_ = [2, 4, 3]
>>> print(sum([[x]*y for x,y in zip(char_, int_)], []))
>>> ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c']
```

Alternative:

```
list(itertools.chain.from_iterable([[x]*y for x,y in zip(char_, int_)]))
```

Looks like it is faster than using itertools.

```
>>> timeit.repeat(lambda:list(itertools.chain.from_iterable([[x]*y for x,y in zip(char_, int_)])), number = 1000000)
[1.2130177360377274, 1.115080286981538, 1.1174913379945792]

>>> timeit.repeat(lambda:sum([[x]*y for x,y in zip(char_, int_)], []), number = 1000000)
[1.0470570910256356, 0.9831087450147606, 0.9912429330288433]
```